# Carbon Laravel textual month could not be found Unexpected data found

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am having issue with this date formatting `Sunday 15th March 04:11 PM` trying to use :

```
Carbon::createFromIsoFormat('dddd Do MMMM hh:mm A')
```

But i am getting this exception :

> Error: A textual month could not be found
>   Unexpected data found.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: `Carbon::createFromFormat("d M Y",strtotime('Sunday 15th March 04:11 PM'));`

Comment: You want to format like this `Sunday 15th March 04:11 PM` ? or what ?

Comment: It seems the problem come from the `Do`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use that specific format, using it like this would work

```php
Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('l jS F h:i A','Sunday 15th March 04:11 PM')
```

For the signification of the format, refer to [PHP DATE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Thank you i didn't think to use this function